# How do I stop my program from making random DLL and PDB files associated with my nuget packages when its run?

Tags: c#

[image: The random files being created]

I haven't found any fix for this, am I missing something really obvious? New to stack overflow and don't know about this sort of stuff, so don't butcher me.

Comment: Very unclear what you mean. Showing some sample code of basic NuGet package that demonstrates the behavior would help (review [MCVE] guide before editing). One line C# code file + .nuspec file would be all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

They're not "random". The DLL is the very result of including the nuget packages, otherwise your program can't run at all without calling those DLL. The PDB is for debugging support. You *can* integrate those DLL into a single file with [single file publish](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design_3_0.md), but since you don't complain about other DLL, I don't think you need to go that route.

Comment: I don't see how that answer the question as asked - while indeed those are reasonable DLL/PDB files OP claim seem to be that they did not reference/used those dependencies and yet they show up... (But that's how I see the question - consider to just edit the question to clarify)

Comment: Hm, I see the question as "these DLL & PDB shows up when it's run", but I'll wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: I see how one can read it that way too... I guess I payed too much attention to  at "random DLL and PDB files *associated with my nuget packages*...".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well at all. I do reference/use these dependencies but I didn't understand why they show up in my folder at all, shouldn't they be hidden? Random was terrible word choice, these are dependencies in my project, but how do I hide them from appearing when run?

Comment: You'll probably want to use the single file publish route then. Those dlls will instead get extracted to temporary folders on run.